# Nomad connection error on AWS when accessing Nomad UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, nomad

I am following this tutorial to setup a Nomad parameterized batch job with autoscaling on AWS.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/nomad/tutorials/autoscaler/horizontal-cluster-scaling-on-demand-batch.
Everything worked fine and I was able to access the UI and deploy the job.
However the next day when I tried accessing the UI I didnt get a response back
When I do nomad node status I get the following error

> Error querying node status: Get "http://exampleawsserver:4646/v1/nodes": dial tcp publicip:4646: i/o timeout

All the resources on AWS are still up and running. I need help understanding why I cannot access the Nomad UI or query anything?
Its causing trouble with destroying the resources through terraform destroy as I get the same i/o timeout error when i try to destroy the resources

I have tried accessing the Nomad UI from my local machine but it is not working.
Ideally I should be able to access it and also destroy the resources through terraform destroy.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't stopped and started the EC2 instances at any point?

Comment: @MarkoE No, but I know the issue now, My public IP changed from the ones set in the security group. Once I added an inbound rule to my current public IP I was able to access the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue,
My public IP changed from the ones set in the security group. Once I added an inbound rule to my current public IP I was able to access the EC2 instance.